# Как к существующим документам добавлять пару ключ-значение?

Tags: solr

Доброго времени суток ребят!

Для своего проекта в качестве поиска использую **Solr 9**. Появилась острая необходимость в дополнительном ключ-значение `score`, чтобы отсортировывать документы. Робот постепенно добавляет конечно этот ключ, но есть вероятность того что некоторая часть будет без этого ключа, а без ключа не получается делать сортировку (по крайней мере у меня вызывает ошибку).

Как я могу для всех документов добавить ключ или же сортировать документы у которых нет ключа `score`?